# What does the integrator do in a Delta-Sigma converter?

Tags: adc

This question is in reference and an extension to this earlier question: [How a Delta-Sigma Modulator Works](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67552/how-a-delta-sigma-modulator-works). The role of the integrator was discussed in the comment section but I'm not following at all.

1. In the first and initial cycle where I input **1.015V** and the DAC initially outputs a **0**, the first op-amp essentially acts as a subtractor and outputs the difference - **1.015V** - to the inverting input of the integrator. Assuming the non-inverting input of the integrator is tied to ground, the integrator ramps down from 0V to **-1.015V** then feeds an inverted **-1.015V** to the ADC. Why not just skip the integrator and feed the **1.1015V** directly from the output of the first op-amp to the ADC? The integrator seems not do anything other than delaying the the conversion and inverting the polarity of the signal.
2. On the second cycle, the 8-bit ADC outputs the binary value of (negative) **-1.010V** and through the DAC, I assume the polarity will flip back to positive so the first op-amp will subtract **1.010V** from the original **1.015V** input. The first op-amp outputs (negative) **-0.005V** and the integrator discharge from **-1.015V** to **-0.005V** before feeding **-0.005V** into the ADC. The 8-bit ADC cannot resolve down to 5mV and will output 0. Again, why we add the integrator to delay feeding the **0.005V** error to the ADC?

[image]

Comment: Sigma refers to summation ... which is the discrete domain name for integration.

Comment: Right and I don't get why we need sigma/integration/summation here ... the ADC can take the error voltage from the delta op-amp, why wait for the sigma op-amp to integrate to the same error voltage?

Comment: Have you studied control theory, inc. PID controllers yet?

Comment: @user_1818839 not really. other than knowing the basic notation but not deep enough into the maths of a graph

Comment: This can help ?   https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/interactive-design-tools/sigma-delta-adc-tutorial.html

Comment: @Antonio51 yes and very much does!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Assuming the non-inverting input of the integrator is tied to ground,
> the integrator ramps down from 0V to -1.015V then feeds an inverted
> -1.015V to the ADC.*

and

> *The integrator seems not do anything other than delaying the the
> conversion and inverting the polarity of the signal.*

The integrator symbol used in the original answer is a triangle (like an op-amp) but it has one input terminal and one output terminal. It therefore **shouldn't** be regarded as an op-amp integrator because an op-amp integrator is in fact an inverting integrator. Regard it as a pure mathematical integrator where a constant positive input produces a positive ramping output.

This means that after a short time during which the integrator has magnified the error (due to integration), the ADC output becomes one LSB higher. This now forces the DAC to be one LSB higher and, the output from the subtractor must now become negative. This then causes the integrator to ramp down. In effect, the ADC output toggles between a slightly low digital value and a slightly high digital value. The ratio of high time to low time can be used to estimate more precisely the actual analogue input value.

Maybe it's worth a simulation with a 2 volt p-p sinewave input and we make a comparison between a regular 4-bit conversion and a 4-bit sigma-delta conversion: -

[image]

Here's the waveforms side by side of the DAC outputs: -

[image]

As you can see, both systems share the same input, reference and conversion clock and, both use 4-bit resolution components but, can you see that at the top and bottom parts of the sinewave, the sigma-delta output is clearly a lot busier than the regular DAC - it's hunting around the true input value due to the extra process of sigma (difference) then delta (integration).

Here's an easier view of the valley of the sinewave: -

[image]

Use right-click to open the image in a new tab to see better resolution. Here's a comparative view using part of a triangle wave: -

[image]

The sigma-delta output is clearly trying to improve the basic 4 bit resolution by hunting around the true analogue value. Here's what it's like using a 2-bit ADC and DAC: -

[image]

And here we have a 1-bit ADC and DAC: -

[image]

The sigma delta converter is producing goods that are much more amenable to extracting a truer version of the input signal.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the mix up with op-amp integrator. When you say the integrator "magnified the error", do you really mean the value that the integrator ramping into / trying to reach? Because the error feeding through the DAC and return into the subtractor should decrease per cycle.  Or am I misunderstanding something again...

Comment: *the integrator has magnified the error (due to integration)* - i.e. normal integration action on the **error** input (where **error** is the output of the subtractor). The error doesn't feed through the DAC. The DAC output is an approximation of the real input (as is the ADC output). Let's get the terminology right first.

Comment: I think I'm starting to get the idea. The ADC in a Sigma Delta is a one bit comparator instead of an 8-bit ADC. If the DAC has to switch between max and min voltage (+/- Vref), does that mean the 1-bit ADC / comparator compared to the mid-point of the DAC's Vref?

Comment: To put it in a different way, if the Vref is 5V and the 1-Bit ADC / comparater is tied to 1V, then the Sigma Delta ADC will process an input of 5V and -4V where 1V will output bit stream of 000...000. Not sure if that make any practical sense, I just ask to confirm my understanding

Comment: Truly, a sigma delta can use any bit-size ADC it wants but, clearly with speeds ramping up yearly, the attraction is to make 1 bit ones because... that's just a really good comparator. I'm not sure I'm following your numbers - maybe I should have shown the integrator output in my screen shots from my sim.

Comment: The last ADC between the integrator and the DAC, be it 1-bit or n-bit, has to have a Vref itself. If for 1-bit, the ADC's Vref should be the mid-point of the Vref of the DAC.

Comment: Yes, for a 1 bit ADC it is the mid-point.

Answer (score 4):

Without the integrator only the error signal will be fed back to the ADC. So for a 1.015V input and a 1.010V feedback signal, only 0.005V will be applied to the ADC for the next conversion, this is definitely not what you want.

The integrator makes it so the error signal is integrated onto the original input voltage so the signal applied to the ADC wiggles back and forth around 1.010V and 1.020V.

Multiple digital samples then average 1.015V.

Edit: Extra clarification of the steps involved:

- Initially, 1.015V is applied and the ADC output is 0V, so the error fed back to the integrator is 1.015V. The integrator starts integrating upwards.
- Let's say the integrator has only made it to 0.51V when the next ADC conversion starts. The error fed back to the integrator is now 0.5V (1.015V - 0.51V @ 10mV ADC resolution). So the integrator will now be integrating slower but it'll still move upwards.
- Eventually, the integrator will make it to 1.020V (because for any value below that there'll still be an error that causes it to continue integrating upwards). Now the error signal fed back changes sign (-0.005V). The integrator will start integrating downward.
- Once the integrator voltage drops low enough for the feedback signal to reach 1.010V the error changes sign again (0.005V) and the integrator moves upward again.
- Cycle repeats as long as input voltage does not change.

Comment: I don't see how it could possibly wiggle between 1.010V and 1.020V. The integrator will charge or discharge the capacitor to whatever voltage feeds into the inverting input.  Regardless of previous voltage (1.015V, 1.030V or 1.045V etc.), the integrator will output 0.005V error voltage to the ADC. It just takes longer time.

Comment: That's not how a integrator works. For a 0V input the integrator will simply hold it's previous output voltage, whatever that was. It integrates the input voltage onto the previous output voltage over time. Added some clarification about the steps involved.

Comment: The point of the integrator is that if the error is nonzero, it eventually forces the output of the ADC to change state. The long-term average value of those output states is a better approximation to the actual value of the analog input.

Comment: The extra clarification with I/O values answers multiple textual misinterpretations I originally had.  But now that the Sigma Delta ADC outputs the same value (with fluctuation) as that from a normal 8-bit ADC, what's the point of that? The normal 8-bit ADC has fewer components, output the same value without fluctuation and faster.

Comment: @KMC The 8-bit ADC in this example has a resolution of 10mV. So it cannot measure 1.015V, the digitized result will be 1.010V. By adding the integrator the digitized result alternates between 1.010V and 1.020V. By averaging the result of multiple ADC conversions in software you can get closer to the actual value of 1.015V

Comment: @Unimportant so the bigger purpose of the integrator is to allow the the LSB to fluctuate between ±LSB/2 to gain an extra digit in accuracy, and along the way also filter out some noise by the integration?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of an ADC is to transmit a digital version of the analog signal to another system or to store it for later use.

The decoder/receiver of the bit stream will be integrating it to recreate the analog signal that the receiver will be generating.

The integrator in the sigma-delta converter is to generate the same signal that the receiver has to generate an error signal that represents the difference between what the receiver has and the current input - the receiver does not have the output of the ADC so that is not the correct error to use.

The encoding/decoding system may also use more complex integration methods (eg multiple integrators in sequence for second or third order sigma-delta converters). In those case the encoding end must also use the same approach.